# Batch: Shutdown PC if a Program isn't Running?

Tags: batch-file, shutdown

Is there a batch command that will check if a program is running and shutdown the PC if it isn't?

Answer (score 1):

Thats Possible, example looking for running Internet explorer:

```
@echo off

tasklist /fi "imagename eq iexplore.exe" | find /I "iexplore.exe" > nul
if errorlevel 1 goto SHUTDOWN

echo IE is already running
goto DONE

:SHUTDOWN
shutdown -s -f -t 0

goto DONE

:DONE
exit
```

**EDIT**

if you want to Loop this command use this:

```
@echo off
:loop
tasklist /fi "imagename eq iexplore.exe" | find /I "iexplore.exe" > nul
if errorlevel 1 goto SHUTDOWN

echo IE is already running
goto DONE

:SHUTDOWN
shutdown -s -f -t 0

goto DONE

:DONE
REM wait 5 sec
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 -w 5000 > NUL
goto loop
```

Comment: What's with the `set SR=%~d0%~p0`?

Comment: The current path of the Batch ;)

Comment: I'm writing this in Windows 8, but will be executing it on Windows 7. Right now always says IE is running. Is it different for 8?

Comment: Ok. I'll try it this afternoon. I'll trying running it now on Win8.1 with a different program (the actual executable I needed this for)

Comment: It's an extractor I made in iexpress. I want to computer to shutdown when it's finished executing. If there's another method of shutting down after extracting, please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Just for a one liner

```
for /l %%# in (1 0 2) do (tasklist|find /i "program.exe">nul ||(shutdown -s -f -t 0 & exit /b))
```

Create a loop starting in 1 until 2 with a step of 0, check if program.exe in tasklist output. If it fails run shutdown and exit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little recursive function that should do what you want as well.

```
@echo off
setlocal

call :ShutDownIfNotRunning Process.exe
exit /b

:ShutDownIfNotRunning
tasklist /FI "imagename eq %~1" | Findstr /i "%~1">nul
if not errorlevel 1 ( 
echo %~1 is running. & goto ShutDownIfNotRunning
) ELSE ( shutdown -s -f -t 0 )
exit /b
```